# Palindrome product

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the largest product of 2 three-digit numbers that is a palindrome. The answer is 993 * 913 = 906609.

This is my code:

```
x = 123

until x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i
  999.downto(100) do |i|
    i.downto(100) do |j|
      x = i * j
      puts "#{i} * #{j} = #{x}"
    end
  end
end

puts x
```

I wrapped everything in an `until` statement that is supposed to check its palindrome-ness, but my code keeps going on even after it hits the correct value. Does anyone see what I am doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and think about what you are telling your code to do in plain english:

"Until x is a palindrome, do this doubly nested loop to completion"

The until loop is never breaking because it is FULLY running both loops BEFORE checking if x is a palindrome. The solution would be to instead break when you find a palindrome Try this:

```
999.downto(100) do |i|
  i.downto(100) do |j|
    x = i * j
    break if x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i
    puts "#{i} * #{j} = #{x}"
  end
  break if x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i
end

puts x
```

Ah but now we have arrived at another problem - looping in this way does not guarantee that the product will be the highest product. We can modify slightly to achieve this:

```
palindromes = []

999.downto(100) do |i|
  i.downto(100) do |j|
    x = i * j
    palindromes << x if x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i
  end
end

puts palindromes.max
```

This probably isn't the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Even if your code worked, it would pick `995 * 585 = 580085` as there is no logic to pick the palindrome with highest value.

So, you may want to collect all palindromes in an array and then find `max` from that array as shown below:

```
arr = []
999.downto(100) do |i|
    i.downto(100) do |j|
      x = i * j
      arr << x if x.to_s == x.to_s.reverse
    end
end

p arr.max
#=> 906609
```

Comment: There's no need to maintain a whole new array. Just maintain a `max` variable and every time a product is palindromic, update `max` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the condition is never being checked, as the inner loops run until they finish without returning the execution to the **until** loop

You could to it this way

```
x = 123
999.downto(100) do |i|
  i.downto(100) do |j|
    x = i * j
    puts "#{i} * #{j} = #{x}"
    break if x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i
  end
end

puts x
```

Anyway this (as your initial solution if it worked) will not give you the biggest palindrome, but the first one it finds.

Answer (score -1):

The outer `until` loop is controlled by the condition `x == x.to_s.reverse.to_i`, but the inner two `downto` loops are not controlled by that condition. When the condition is satisfied in the middle of the two `downto` loops, that does not have any effect in stopping in the middle of the two `downto` loops, it only stops the `until` loop from continuing to the next iteration.

As pointed out by Wand Maker, it also does not give the correct result even if it worked. The problem is with the order of iteration. You are decrementing `i` and `j` in the order such as:

```
...
..., [i, j],     [i, j - 1], ...,
..., [i - 1, j], [i -1, j - 1], ...,
...
```

Under this order, you are assuming for example that `i * (j - 1)` is greater than `(i - 1) * j`, and hence if they both satisfy the condition, the earlier among them, `i * (j - 1)`, should be picked as the greater number, stopping the iteration to go on to the latter. But that assumption about the ordering is wrong.